# Is there a lounge for use at Nairobi airport by departing BA passengers?

Tags: british-airways, qatar-airways, lounges, nbo

Travelling as [OneWorld Emerald](http://www.oneworld.com/ffp/emerald-privileges) (American Airlines Executive Platinum, if it matters), on British Airways, is there a lounge I will be able to use at Nairobi airport at the beginning of February 2015? According to [the oneworld website](http://www.oneworld.com/ffp/lounge-access/), the BA lounge at Nairobi is currently closed "Due to fire in main terminal", but [this was in 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nairobi_airport_fire); perhaps the website hasn't been updated?

Alternatively, can I use the Swissport lounge there? It looks as if those flying on Qatar Airways (which are a Oneworld partner) are eligible, but it's not a Qatar Airways lounge itself, so I would assume that's not automatic.

Comment: The [FlyerTalk BA Executive Club lounge info](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1494983-ba-lounge-database-africa.html#post21290368) suggests it's still closed, and doesn't list any alternatives

Comment: Gagravarr, thanks, but the last update there was also in Dec '13, so only shortly after the fire. Was just wondering if there was some more up-to-date info.

Comment: Post a new thread in the BAEC forum and I'm sure someone'll tell you within an hour or so, it's a very active place!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of January 2015: Lounge = no, basic refreshments = yes

There are two pertinent BAEC FlyerTalk threads covering this:

- [Replacement BA Lounge at NBO???](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1504755-replacement-ba-lounge-nbo.html)
- [BA Nairobi Lounge Update?](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1631248-ba-nairobi-lounge-update.html)

Based on that, until the new terminal building is finished at some point in the next year, there is no lounge that BA is using. (BA aren't using the Swissport one). On arriving at the terminal, you'll clear first security, then get to checkin. After checking, you'll then go through another set of security. Finally, after that, you'll be directed to a waiting area at the gate.

If you're flying in First or Club World, or have suitable BA / OneWorld status, you'll be directed into a different seating area. In here you'll apparently find a trestle table with some refreshments on. Looks to be snacks, some soft drinks, some booze, and some newspapers. You can find photos of what it was like a few months ago in the threads

Comment: Having done this journey now, I can confirm (as of Feb 2015), that these still seem to be the arrangements. Two gotchas: there are no toilet facilities in the gate area (which require you to go through another security check first). Also, BA do *not* allow water through the gate security check even if you have a reciept (contrary to what I was told in the shop). But the "status" gate area refreshment counter does have bottles of water.